# port 8080 PID/node always restart

Tags: bash, kubuntu, 20.04, nodejs

i'm using kubuntu 20.04 when i type `sudo netstat -plten`  in terminal, port 8080 -- PID/node always there, and when i kill use `sudo lsof -t -i:8080` port 8080 always restart and use another PID.
how to kill permanently port 8080 ?

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5146/node
```

Comment: Could you add more information to your question? For example, what's running on port 8080? That might help debug the issue.

I see you used the tag nodejs, so I am assuming it's a Node API? Do you maybe have something going on in development mode that makes it always restart?

Comment: thanks for your answer, and no, i don't have any development mode, i knew that when i want to use port 8080, and port 8080 is used, and this is when i sudo netstat -plten


tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5146/node

Comment: i can solve this, is from snap wekan always running in port 8080, thanks